# How to iterate over all cookies and remove them Java

Tags: java, cookies

Declaring cookie variable

```
private List<String> cookies;
```

Collecting cookie

```
    setCookies(httpConn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie"));
```

calling cookie with a method :

```
public List<String> getCookies() {
    return cookies;
}
```

method for setting cookies :

```
public void setCookies(List<String> cookies) {
    this.cookies = cookies;
}
```

Reseting cookie in a constructor

```
public void Reset() {
    System.out.println("start clear and set....................");
    if (HttpClient.getCookies() != null) {
        for (Iterator iterator = HttpClient.getCookies().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Object next = iterator.next();
            System.out.println(next);
            if (next != null) {

            iterator.remove();
            System.out.println("clearing....................");
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("cleared ,setting....................");
}
```

output

```
start clear and set....................
PHPSESSID=vkqcf64f79bptfvf9e8volea23; path=/
start clear and set....................
_smasher_session=bb09471bbf02ad62a937c1cb75b7bf6c; domain=domain.com; path=/
```

How do i iterate and clear all cookies ?

Comment: Hello there. Your question is seemingly missing a question. What do you want to know?

Comment: Sorry. How do i iterate and clear all cookies ?

Comment: You must be swallowing exceptions somewhere. Don't do that. Also please read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just clear your list instead of iterating and removing

```
setCookies(Collections.emptyList());
```

`HttpClient.getCookies()` may not be returning the same object each time and so if you clear one instance, that may not clear the initial instance that you set using setCookies.